# First API request fails because of CORS the following request are successful, REACT.js at the frontend and .NETCORE on the server side

Tags: reactjs, iis, cors

I am making  request to a .NetCore API from a React.js client, I have configured the CORS however every time a new device makes a request or if I clear my browser data the first request fails by this error
"Access to fetch at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-  Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

The following requests are successful as expected since the configuration has been done on the server side.

```
        fetch(GET_PAYMENT_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode:'cors',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(paymentUrlRequest),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {

        })
        .catch(errorr => {

        });
```

I expect the first request to be successful on a new device or even if the client clears browser data

Comment: Just like the error says "No 'Access-Control- Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". So your response **from your backend** must include an allow-origin header.

Comment: Noted, but how does it fail initially and then succeed on the subsequent requests?

Comment: Neither `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` nor `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` belong in a request; those are _response_ headers. You can safely drop them from your request.

Comment: Intermittent CORS errors may be caused by caching issues. Do you allow multiple origins in your CORS configuration? And if so, do your responses include a `Vary: Origin` header?

Comment: @jub0bs Yes I allow multiple origins in the CORS, No they do not include Vary: Origin header, let me see to that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jub0bs in the comments,
the server side is configured to allow listed origins, thus the response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' cannot be static or '*' for all, that's when we use 'Vary': 'Origin' so that the user agent will fetch a response that includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, rather than using the cached response from the previous non-CORS request that lacks `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Here is the link [CORS protocol and HTTP caches](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches)

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. But instead of re-implementing CORS manually (which is error-prone), you should rely on some proven CORS middleware that, among other things, knows when and how to use the `Vary` header. .NET has one; use it.